# Reuse a socket again?

Tags: java, sockets

Simple question, I know that if you just use ".close()" or just set null on a socket, you still can not reuse it. But if you were to set it to null and then say " = new Socket();" on the used socket, can you use it again?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you say `new Socket();` it won't be using already closed socket, it gets you new `Socket`. So, that is not re-use. You are just **re-using the reference variable**, not `Socket` object.

Answer (score 1):

That's not reuse. That's creation of a new object. The only thing being reused here is the *variable.*

Answer (score 1):

You are mixing concepts: when you do `socket = new Socket()` you are just reusing the variable name, but the object is another one. So you are not reusing the same socket, just creating a new one that can be accessed from the same variable.

This is true for any variable actually. Not just sockets.